# How can I Merge Two Binary Trees in ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have 2 binary trees [1,3,2,5] and [2,1,3,null,4,null,7] and I need to merge them into single tree using ruby programming language.
So the output should be [3,4,5,5,4,null,7]

I tried to traverse both the given trees in a preorder fashion.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using recursion:

```
def merge_trees(t1, t2)
  return if t1 == nil
  return if t2 == nil
  t1.val += t2.val
  t1.left = merge_trees(t1.left, t2.left);
  t1.right = merge_trees(t1.right, t2.right);
end
```

Comment: 'Merging' isn't specific enough, are you trying to add nodes from the first tree to the second tree or from the second tree to the first tree. You could also be adding nodes from each tree to a new tree. Merging is a very broad term in this case.

Comment: @Виктор, all the answers submitted to date assume that a third tree is wanted, without mutating (the arrays associated with) those being merged. That is in line with the common assumption on SO that objects should not be mutated unless the asker specific asks for that. The asker's code may suggest that the array associated with the first tree should be modified, but if that is desired one can always set it equal to the result obtained without mutating the trees.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I had some misunderstandings about binary tree representation using arrays and merging, your answer and some googling helped me solve that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tree1 = [1, 3, 2, 5]
tree2 = [2, 1, 3, nil, 4, nil, 7]

[tree1.size, tree2.size].max.times.map { |i|
  tree1[i].nil? && tree2[i].nil? ? nil : tree1[i].to_i + tree2[i].to_i }
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 5, 4, nil, 7]
```

Note that `arr[i] #=> nil` if `i >= arr.size` and `nil.to_i #=> 0`.

For readers unfamiliar with the use of an array for storing the content of a binary tree (which, a half-hour ago, included me) I have provided below a professionally-drawn picture that shows the binary trees corresponding to the three arrays given in the question.

[image]

In each array the node at index `i` has a left node at index `2*i+1` and a right node at index `2*i+2`. In the middle array, for example, the node at index `0` (`2`) has its left node (`1`) at index `2*0+1 #=> 1` and its right node (`3`) at index `2*0+2 #=> 2`. Similarly the node at index `1` (`1`) has a right node (`4`) at index `2*1+2 #=> 3`, but no left node because the element at index `2*1+1 #=> 3` is `nil`.

The rule for merging two binary trees is, "If two nodes overlap (i.e., the nodes are in the same position in both graphs), then sum node values up as the new value of the merged node; otherwise, the node that is present (not `nil` in the associated array) will be used as the node of new tree."<sup>1</sup> For example, in the merged tree, node `3`'s right node `5` equals `2` (from the first tree) plus `3` (from the second tree), whereas node `7` is taken from the second tree because the first has no node in that position.

<sup>1. See [this article](https://leetcode.com/articles/merge-two-binary-trees/), which also discusses algorithms for merging binary trees.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
[[1,3,2,5], [2,1,3,nil,4,nil,7]].
  sort_by(&:size).
  rotate.
  reduce(&:zip).
  map { |elems| elems.compact.reduce(&:+) }
#⇒ [3, 4, 5, 5, 4, nil, 7]
```